# Symfony2 and Nginx, route by hostname

Tags: symfony, nginx, symfony-routing

I have one Symfony2 project named SymfonyProject.

I had until now one nginx config file that points to that project with `www.symfonyproject.com`

I developed some static twig pages in the SymfonyProject which I would like to access with another url: `www.symfonyproject2.com`

So, the www.symfonyproject2.com will only access one route from the SymfonyProject.

How to do this with Nginx? I created another config file in sites enabled, but don't know how to redirect trafic to a specific symfony2 route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your nginx can use the `www.symfonyproject2.com` as alias and inside symfony you can use a route which is going to match by hostname:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/hostname_pattern.html

This should be enough to solve your problem!

Let me know if it helped you!